# Map Function using list implementation haskell

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension, map-function

Is there a way to write an implementation of the Haskell `map` function using list implementation?

I keep getting an error and I do not think I am on the right track. This is what I have:

```
map' :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map' _ [] = []
map' xs ys = [ (x, y) | x <- xs | y <- ys ]
```

Any help or link that will guide me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: The type signature says `map`, but the implementation says `zip` (with a redundant case).

Comment: The first argument to `map` is a function (as per the type signature).  `map` applies the function to each element of the list, returning the list of results).  You are creating pairs from elements of 2 lists, which is `zip`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you mean "comprehension", instead of "implementation".

Either way, this would work:

```
map' f as = [f a | a <- as]
map' (* 2) [1..5]
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that

```
map' f xs = [f x | x <- xs]
```

desugars to

```
map' f xs = do x <- xs
               return $ f x
```

which desugars to

```
map' f xs = xs >>= return . f
```

which is the well-known definition (if you replace `map'` with `fmap`) for defining a `Functor` instance from a `Monad` instance (thus proving that all monads are also functors).

Specifically, it shows that a list comprehension is simply a disguised version of the definition of `map` in terms of monadic operators.