# Implementaion of filter function haskell

Tags: list, haskell, filter, functional-programming, list-comprehension

Is there a way to write an implementation of the Haskell filter function using list comprehension?

An error keeps appearing and I am stumped on how to approach it. This is what I have:

```
filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' _ [] = []
filter' f xs = [f x | x <- xs]
```

Any guidance or link would be much appreciated.

Comment: Nice overview of list comprehensions in haskell: https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension

Comment: You should really put some more effort into solving these questions yourself. It looks like all you did was copy the solution from [the `map` implementation that was given to you in your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46876590/5743988). In the future, please explain more of your thought process on why you're stumped, so that people can help you better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can write it as:

```
filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' f xs = [x | x <- xs, f x]
```

If you add a an expression in list comprehension that evaluates to a boolean, then you have added a filter to the list comprehension: only if `f x` evaluates to `True` here, we will add `x` to the list.

Note that writing `filter' _ [] = []` is useless: if you provide an empty list, then the list comprehension will also return an empty list, since `x` will never pick a value out of `xs` with `x <- xs`.

But usually it is better to use the [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) builtin.